# AngularJS Controller Factory rest JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, rest

I am trying to call a factory from multiple controllers. This factory get JSON data. I can succeed it when I tried calling from controller directly. Now I just added a factory and there is be no error in console but nothing come to screen also. Here is the code:

html template:

```
<!-- Schools -->
<div class="row">
    <h3 class="text-center">Schools and Associations</h3>
    <ul class="gallery gallery1" ng-controller="SchoolsCtrl">
        <li ng-repeat="school in schools" class="card">
            <a ng-href="{{school.url}}" target="_blank">
                <img ng-src="{{school.thumbUrl}}" class="img-responsive">
                <p class="text-center">{{school.name}}</p>
                <p class="text-center">{{school.time}}</p>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

controller.js:

```
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', ['bootstrapLightbox', 'ngAnimate']);

mainApp.controller('CompaniesCtrl', function($scope, GalleryService) {
$scope.companies = GalleryService.getObjects('app/common/companies.json');
});

mainApp.controller('WorksCtrl', function($scope, GalleryService) {
$scope.works = GalleryService.getObjects('app/common/freelance-projects.json');
});

mainApp.controller('SchoolsCtrl', function ($scope, GalleryService) {
$scope.schools = GalleryService.getObjects("app/common/schools.json");
});
```

service.js:

```
mainApp.factory('GalleryService', function ($http) {
    return {
        getObjects: function (jsonUrl) {
            $http.get(jsonUrl)
                .success(function (data) {
                    return data; 
                })
                .error(function (data, status, error, config) {
                    return [{heading:"Error", description: "Could not load json data"}];
                });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to retrieve data from factory function `getObjects` you should return a promise from `getObjects` function with `.then` function to chain promise. Inside a controller you can make `getObjects` call with `.then` function callbacks to receive response.

**Factory**

```
mainApp.factory('GalleryService', function ($http) {
    return {
        getObjects: function (jsonUrl) {
            return $http.get(jsonUrl)
                .then(function (resp) {
                    return resp.data; 
                }, function (res) {
                    return [{heading:"Error", description: "Could not load json data"}];
                });
        }
    }
});
```

**Controller**

```
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', ['bootstrapLightbox', 'ngAnimate']);

mainApp.controller('CompaniesCtrl', function($scope, GalleryService) {
  GalleryService.getObjects('app/common/companies.json').then(function(data){
    $scope.companies = data;
  });
});
```

Comment: Pleased to hear that. Thanks ;)